Error Opening foldable avd: Device pixel_fold requires foldable feature, but the system image does not support
I was creating a foldable avd using android studio but when i tried to run i got this.
┌──(shivanshu㉿kali)-[~/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_32.avd]
└─$ emulator -avd Pixel_Fold_API_32

INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-shivanshu/emu-crash-35.1.4.db, detection is enabled for process: 21993
INFO    | Android emulator version 35.1.4.0 (build_id 11672324) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /home/shivanshu/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-32/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-shivanshu/emu-crash-35.1.4.db, detection is enabled for process: 21993
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
WARNING | folded height 2092 is larger than lcd height 1840, reduced to lcd height.
ERROR   | Device pixel_fold requires foldable feature, but the system image does not support. Quit.


You must use Android API 34 - UpsideDownCake

